Rpi.GPIO module not found when trying to debug Python code
I'm new to Python programming and have limited experience with Raspberry Pi's.
I'm using a windows pc to develop some python code for a Raspberry Pi4.  I would like to be able to debug the code on the windows pc (7 or 11) before downloading to the Pi.
I'm currently getting the Module not found error: no module named 'RPi'
Is there any way I can simulate/emulate RPI.GPIO, just to debug the code?
Here is a link to some code I found on the site but I can't get it to work, keeps giving me a print a error.
BOARD = 1
OUT = 1
IN = 1

def setmode(a):
   print a
def setup(a, b):
   print a
def output(a, b):
   print a
def cleanup():
   print 'a'
def setwarnings(flag):
   print 'False'

Thanks for your help.

Incidentally the code you listed would generate other errors. It appears to be old python2; Python3 syntax is different.

You can NOT emulate hardware (at least not without a lot of specialised equipment).
Any of the GPIO libraries REQUIRE the hardware included in the Pi and are simply an interface to this hardware.
It would be possible to write a library with dummy code to let GPIO code be tested, but I am unaware of any.
NOTE I strongly suggest that you DO NOT start with RPi.GPIO. While this was very popular code, it is dependent on a direct interface to hardware much of the support is no longer present in current OS.
You probably won't understand the above comment but I suggest if you want to code on a Pi you start with gpiozero.

Thanks for the info.  I'll check out gpiozero
